# Display 1 if all grouped rows are 1 otherwise display 0

Tags: mysql, select, group-by

I have this query:

```
select *, sum(services.amount) as service_amount from invoices
left join projects using(project_id)
left join services using(invoice_id)
where client_id = ?
group by project_id
order by issue_date desc
```

In the table `invoices` I have a column `paid` which is a `tinyint` that is `1` or `0`.

Adding on to the query I have, how can I make the returning `paid` column display `1` if all the grouped `paid` column rows equal `1` otherwise display `0` for the `paid` column?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you could make use of the **min** keyword in sql. Something like:

```
select MIN(paid), sum(services.amount) as service_amount from invoices
left join projects using(project_id)
left join services using(invoice_id)
where client_id = ?
group by project_id
order by issue_date desc
```

Answer (score 2):

Select min(paid) maybe? Should be 0 if there's a 0 and 1 otherwise.